# User Input Time - Android

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to program games using Android Studio. I am using the book "Beginning Android Games" to do it. There is a some code in the book that says

```
package com.helloworld.gravitas.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class HelloWorldActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    int touchCount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Touch me!");
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(button);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        touchCount++;
        button.setText("Touched me " + touchCount + " time(s)");
    }
}
```

When I run it in the SDK I get the error:

`String literal in setText can not be translated. Use android resources instead.`
 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did `touchCount` get initialized? In `onCreate` initialize `touchCount` to zero and try again.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: @DigitalNinja it's a primitive... It's already initialized at zero